# How to make a lines graphic with a monthly evolution of a variable in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to create a a line graph but I think my graph is incorrect. How can I fix it?

```
ggplot(data=df,
      aes(x=mensual, y=totalcyc, colour=Districts)) +
  geom_line()
```

I have this df:

```
 Districts mensual totalcyc
1   Berri1  1   10072
2   Berri1  2   10669
3   Berri1  3   12788
4   Berri1  4   53651
5   Berri1  5   108808
6   Berri1  6   130536
7   Berri1  7   148493
8   Berri1  8   141803
9   Berri1  9   141808
10  Berri1  10  107566
11  Berri1  11  44100
12  Berri1  12  14205
13  Boyer   1   3285
14  Boyer   2   3122
15  Boyer   3   3976
16  Boyer   4   21895
17  Boyer   5   43532
18  Boyer   6   96513
```

[image: img]

where the month represents january, february, etc. and total people represents the total people who visited that place every month.
I need to draw a line graphic of the monthly evolution of people in each place.

I wrote this code:

```
ggplot(data=pob_tidy4,
      aes(x=mensual, y=totalcyc, colour=Districts)) +
  geom_line()
```

I got a graphic but it is not what I must show.

I got this graph and I am not sure it is correct

[image: Graph]

[image: graph3]

Comment: I updated my question with a link to the picture I got.

Comment: My previous comment got deleted, but without knowing what you're trying to do, we can't help you get it to what is "correct"

Comment: Camille, I need to draw a line graphic of the monthly evolution of people in each place, I wrote this in my question. Thank you.

Comment: Right, but you're making a frequency polygon (`geom_freqpoly`), which shows a distribution. It's similar to a density curve.  A line chart would generally be `geom_line`. That's why what is correct vs incorrect is unclear. Additionally, the code you've posted doesn't get me anything like the plot you show—your code would draw the distribution, which isn't what's in your plot

Comment: You are right, I tried many times with some codes so I did not upgrade correctly. I converted the variable mensual to a factor to have months in the axes, but when I make the graph, I have this error: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic? but then I set group=1 but the graph got wrong as I show in graph3. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want months to be a continuous variable, as would generally be used for a line chart, don't make it a factor. If you need to adjust the x-axis breaks, do that later in `scale_x_continuous`. Otherwise, you've again got charts that aren't created by the code & data you've shown, so at this point I'm voting to close as off topic

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple geom_line would work

```
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = totalpeople,y = as.factor(month), colour = Place)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you Yazid, but I would like to have month in the x axes and when I tried to do it with your code I got this error: geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ggplot(data=pob_tidy4,
      aes(x=mensual, y=totalcyc)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=Districts)
```